# Encoding.GetChars( "iso-8859-9" ) C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, character-encoding

I have the following code in C#, which I need to convert to PHP:

```
turkishEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");
var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(a => (byte)a).ToArray();
inAlphabet = turkishEncoding.GetChars(bytes);
```

Does anyone know either the equivlant of this in PHP, or what the output that gets stored in **inAlphabet** is?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php